# Why does my onclick have to be split in two to work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management, zustand

In order to get familiar with Zustand, I'm coding a demo project to associate tags with contacts and contacts with tags. My problems occurs when I delete a contact or a tag.

Here is the codesandbox of the project :
[ReactZustandFirestore project](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Ahmed-Kem/ReactZustandFirestore/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000i2a65o17oo5g8%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000e2a65xiq96b3b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000g2a654vq11m4i%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000h2a653y0g0lm9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clmrwyqi7000e2a65xiq96b3b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000e2a65xiq96b3b%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmrxewnz015o2a65jqriw12g%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000d2a65a1zh5fyz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FContact%252Findex.jsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrxewnz015o2a65jqriw12g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmrwyqi7000h2a653y0g0lm9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000h2a653y0g0lm9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmrwz0co00mu2a65q27435z1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwz0co00mu2a65q27435z1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clmrwyqi7000g2a654vq11m4i%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000g2a654vq11m4i%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clmrwyxjm00gt2a650tesud9b%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqi7000f2a655hul5e6m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clmrwyqvp001ce5gr2oof7b9c%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clmrwyxjm00gt2a650tesud9b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

I will explain my probleme with the Contact component. The Tag component works the same.

My "handleDeleteContact" should :

1. Remove my contact from tags where it appears.
2. Clear all tags of my contact.
3. Delete the contact.

This last step doesn't work and the contact is still listed.

When I split my "handleDeleteContact" into two handlers like :

- handleClearContact :

1. Remove my contact from tags where it apears.
2. Clear all tags of my contact.

- handleRemoveContact :

3. Delete the contact.

And then affect them to two different buttons. clicking on the first button then the second delete my contact successfully.

I'm sure I'm missing something but don't know what. I rechecked the stores for contact and tag without finding the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)